# add_rewrite_tag broke permalinks that doesn't use that specific tag

Tags: custom-post-types, filters, url-rewriting, rewrite-tag

I have a custom post type that I'd like to have a permalink slug based on its taxonomy. All the posts of this CPT have one, and only one, term always marked on this specific taxonomy.
That's my code:

```
function plugin_domain_register_post_type(){

    add_rewrite_tag('%event_segment%', '([^&]+)');

    register_post_type( 'event',
        array(
            'public' => true,
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => '%event_segment%'),
            'has_archive' => false,
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'supports' => array( 'title', 'thumbnail')
        )
    );

}
add_action( 'init', 'plugin_domain_register_post_type' );

function plugin_domain_permalinks($post_link, $post) {
    if (is_object($post) && $post->post_type === 'event') {
        $terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'segments');
        if ($terms) {
            return str_replace('%event_segment%' , $terms[0]->slug, $post_link);
        }
    }
    return $post_link;
}
add_filter('post_type_link', 'plugin_domain_permalinks', 10, 3);
```

Okay, so it actually works, the permalinks changed and it goes to the right post. However, all the posts and pages (everything that's not of this CPT) that **do not** have the `%event_segment%` tag on the slug will literally just display the home page.

I've noticed this happens because of the `add_rewrite_tag('%event_segment%', '([^&]+)');` part. The filter doesn't seem to be the issue, since even without the rewrite tag, it works as intended, and modifies the permalinks.

I don't know if this is relevant, but I'm on a [Varying Vagrant Vagrants](https://varyingvagrantvagrants.org/) development environment, and it uses nginx, not apache.

What's going on here? Is there something I did wrong or forgot to do?

Comment: WordPress determines what to query by the URL pattern- it matches requests against rewrite rules and stops when it finds the first match. Your post type rewrite rules are capturing all of the requests because they are the top-most match. This is why custom post types by default are prefixed with a static string, and tags and categories have a static base, your post type is currently prefixed with something that could contain any value.

Comment: Thank you so so much! I can't believe it was so simple! May I further ask: There is no way to have a completely dynamic URL like I originally intended, without a static string, right?

Comment: @FeelTheNoise I have a similar issue. did you manage to find a solution to your problem? " May I further ask: There is no way to have a completely dynamic URL like I originally intended, without a static string, right"